# Serving create-react-blog in subdirectory

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I need to serve a blog created with [create-react-blog](https://github.com/jamesknelson/create-react-blog) in the /blog subdirectory on my main site. It is served alongside other separate projects created w/ create-react-app (the NodeJS code looks like this):

```
app.use("/blog", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "projects/blog")))
app.get("/blog", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "projects/blog/index.html"));
});
app.get("/blog*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "projects/blog/index.html"));
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('/*', function (req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Where the 'build' folder contains the react production build for the main site and 'projects/blog' contains the build files for the blog created with `create-react-blog`

Navigating to `http://localhost:3001/blog` with this system does indeed render the blog project, but presumably because Navi was built to used from the head directory the blog returns its 404 page. I can then only view the blog if I use the return link on the 404 page to navigate to `http://localhost:3001/` (note: just navigating to `http://localhost:3001/` without going through the blog page properly renders the other react project)

I've tried changing the `homepage` in the `package.json` of the blog to both `/blog` and `.`, changing the `basename` of the Router in the blog project's index.js to `/blog`, changing the `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable to `blog` and `http://localhost:3000/blog`, and changing the `navi.config.js` file to add `/blog` in front of each item in the `getPagePathname` function (from

```
import path from 'path'

export const renderPageToString = require.resolve('./src/renderPageToString')

/**
 * Get the file to write each URL to during the build
 */
export function getPagePathname({ url }) {
  if (url.pathname === '/rss') {
    return 'rss.xml'
  }
  if (url.pathname === '/') {
    return 'index.html'
  }
  return path.join(url.pathname.slice(1), 'index.html')
}
```

to

```
import path from 'path'

export const renderPageToString = require.resolve('./src/renderPageToString')

/**
 * Get the file to write each URL to during the build
 */
export function getPagePathname({ url }) {
  if (url.pathname === '/blog/rss') {
    return 'rss.xml'
  }
  if (url.pathname === '/blog/') {
    return 'index.html'
  }
  return path.join('/blog/', url.pathname.slice(1), 'index.html')
}
```

), none of which worked. I've also tried random combinations of the above approaches, which were also unsuccessful.

Please let me know how this would be accomplished. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours, I was able to move the blog in a fairly roundabout way.

Starting from the template found in the main Github repo mentioned in the first paragraph of the question, I had to do the following combination of things:

1. Change all '/' routes in `routes/index.js` to `/blog/<route>` (i.e. `/` became `/blog`, `/page` became `/blog/page` etc.
2. Change the `blogRoot` in the `withContext` statement to just state `/blog`
3. Change `isViewingIndex` to `req.path === '/blog' || /^\/page\/\d+$/.test(req.path)`
4. In the crawlRoutes function in `tags.js`, add `root='/'` to the beginning of the function
5. Change `navi.config.js` to

```
import path from 'path'

export const renderPageToString = require.resolve('./src/renderPageToString')

/**
 * Get the file to write each URL to during the build
 */
export function getPagePathname({ url }) {
  if (url.pathname === '/blog/rss') {
    return 'rss.xml'
  }
  if (url.pathname === '/blog') {
    return 'index.html'
  }
  return path.join('/blog', url.pathname.slice(1), 'index.html')
}
```

6. Change `renderPageToString.js` to

```
import renderReactPageToString from 'react-navi/create-react-app'
import renderRSSFeedToString from './renderRSSFeedToString'

/**
 * navi-scripts will call this function for each of your site's pages
 * to produce its statically rendered HTML.
 */
async function renderPageToString(props) {
  if (props.url.pathname === '/blog/rss') {
    return await renderRSSFeedToString(props)
  }

  return renderReactPageToString(props)
}

export default renderPageToString
```

Of course, you can make this cleaner by changing /blog to be an environment variable (which I highly recommend).

If there is any better solution I am also open to it.